# Testing my Java/Android app - is my setup wrong?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I just tried to test my first android app using the emulator, it crashed (as expected).  So I load the debug view in Eclipse and now I'm not really sure what I'm looking for...

I see a tab that within the first thread I see a bunch of executions (i guess that's the right word) and they say: `Source not found.` and has a button that reads `Edit Source Lookup Path...`

Is there something wrong with my setup here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with your setup. My advice is:

- As you are still learning Android, use the `logcat` to catch know what causes your app to crash, instead of using the debugger.
- Study how the eclipse debugger works and how to use it (you can learn that writting Java apps, no need of using android)

Comment: I see logCat, but I'm not sure how to read it... the error goes off to the right side of the screen and I can't scroll there...

Comment: Use the logcat command, which is in the tools folder of the sdk installation. Don't use the one that comes with eclipse which sucks.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm very new to anything outside of PHP development, where do I use this command?

Comment: `/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools` Whenever I'm there I try to execute these commands and they don't work

Comment: How are you executing them? Have you tried: `./adb logcat`? No need to create another question :)